# Get complete results for Cassandra select query

Tags: java, cassandra

According to the Cassandra documentation using `execute` for getting the results of a select query does not guarantee to return the full results.

> ResultSet execute(Statement statement) Executes the provided query.
>   This method blocks until at least some result has been received from
>   the database. However, for SELECT queries, it does not guarantee that
>   the result has been received in full. But it does guarantee that some
>   response has been received from the database, and in particular
>   guarantee that if the request is invalid, an exception will be thrown
>   by this method.

So, if I have a API that is supposed to return the complete results for a query, how would I implement it to do so? Right now I create a `Statement` and use the execute method apart of the `Session` class to get the results. But, based on the documentation it seems like that will not always work.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is describing the Paging behavior of the driver. When it says the entire result has not be retrieved in full it means the coordinator has not fully materialized the entire resultset. It does this to prevent large amounts of objects being created on the Coordinator.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.0/com/datastax/driver/core/ResultSet.html

You'll see that the ResultSet (the result of execute) has several methods. But only one `all()` will page through entire resultset and download it to the driver immediately.

If instead you use the `iterator`, the results will be paged from the server in batches as you call `next` on the iterator. This means that only a portion of the ResultSet will ever be pulled down to the driver at a time reducing load on the Server and allowing you to work with large datasets without pulling it all into ram.